# Pandas Split dataframe and get remainder of data row

Tags: python, pandas, deep-learning

I am using this code to split a data frame

```
df_80_split = df.sample(frac=0.8,random_state=200)
```

What I need is to get the remainder of the entries in the original into a new data frame so something like

```
df_20_split = df - df_80_split
```

What would be a good way to code that?

Comment: Is this for a training/testing split of data?

Comment: Yes. For training and validation.

Comment: If you're happy to use packages, then the sklearn `train_test_split` works really well. Docs [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using sklearn's `train_test_split()` is a really good method to use especially for large data sets.

```
#import sklearn method to split training data
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# using your variable names
df_80_split, df_20_split = train_test_split(df, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 200)
```

If you provide the target variable as well you can also split features from targets for training and validation.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
       features, target, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 200)
```

Lots of detail in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the index values of your dataframe are all unique, **a pure-Pandas solution** would be:

```py
df_20_split = df[~df.index.isin(df_80_split.index)]
```

Full code:

```
# Just sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[*'abcdefg']*1000}).sort_values('a').reset_index(drop=True)

# Split the data
df_80_split = df.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=200)

# Get the remainder
df_20_split = df[~df.index.isin(df_80_split.index)]
```

Output:

```py
>>> df_80_split.shape
(5600, 1)

>>> df_20_split.shape
(1400, 1)

>>> 5600 + 1400
7000

>>> df.shape
(7000, 1)
```